# Display values not present in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this tbl_religion with fieldname creldesc

[image]

and tbl_member with these fields 
[image]

and I have this query to count all existing religion in tbl_member and count also the no. of male and female with that religion so i made this query :

```
    SELECT m.creldesc as type,
     COUNT(m.creldesc) as total,
     SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male,
     SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female
    FROM tbl_member as m, tbl_barangay as b, tbl_household as h
    WHERE m.chholdnumber = h.chholdnumber and h.cbrgycode=b.cbrgycode and b.cbrgyname = 'AGAO'
          and m.crelationdesc !='Brgy. Captain'
    GROUP BY m.creldesc
    ORDER BY tot DESC;
```

and get this output :

[image]

what I want to achieve is also display the remaining religion from tbl_religion with 0 as value. I made a left join but get an error. Can someone help me how can I achive that ?

```
   type          total    male    female
Roman Catholic     7       4        3
Baptist            3       1        2
Islam              3       3        0
Iglesia ni Cristo  1       1        0
Free Methodist     1       1        0
Ang Dating Daan    1       0        1
Aglipay/Filipinsta 0       0        0
All the Gospel     0       0        0 
Alpha Omega        0       0        0
and so on.............................
```

Comment: SELECT 
 m.creldesc as type,
 COUNT(m.creldesc) as tot,
 SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male,
 SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female
 FROM tbl_member as m, tbl_barangay as b, tbl_household as h
 LEFT JOIN tbl_religion ON tbl_religion.creldesc=m.creldesc
 WHERE m.chholdnumber = h.chholdnumber and h.cbrgycode=b.cbrgycode and b.cbrgyname = 'AGAO' and m.crelationdesc !='Brgy. Captain'
 GROUP BY m.creldesc
 ORDER BY tot DESC

Comment: @Ullas: He just said: " I made a left join but get an error. " And you said USE A LEFT JOIN !!!

Comment: and got this error error ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "m"
LINE 7:  LEFT JOIN tbl_religion ON tbl_religion.creldesc=m.creldesc

Comment: @SanRyu: I didn't see a `LEFT JOIN` in his code.

Comment: I made a left join but got an error @Ullas

Comment: I think you are looking for a left anti-join, i.e. `a left join b on (blah) where b.id is null`

Comment: Just curious - what's the 'c' prefix for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
        SELECT tbl_member.creldesc AS type, 
            COUNT(tbl_member.creldesc) AS total, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_member.cgender::text = 'Male'::text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS male, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_member.cgender::text = 'Female'::text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS female
        FROM tbl_member
        GROUP BY tbl_member.creldesc

        UNION 

        SELECT b.creldesc AS type, 0 AS total, 0 AS male, 0 AS female
        FROM tbl_religion b
        WHERE NOT (b.creldesc::text IN 
           ( SELECT DISTINCT tbl_member.creldesc FROM tbl_member))
        GROUP BY b.creldesc;
```

and here is it's output :

[image]

that's all :) I used UNION instead of LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Use same joining approach for all tables, like this:

```
SELECT m.creldesc as type, COUNT(m.creldesc) as tot, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female 
FROM tbl_religion 
LEFT JOIN tbl_member as m
ON tbl_religion.creldesc=m.creldesc
LEFT JOIN tbl_household as h
ON m.chholdnumber = h.chholdnumber
LEFT JOIN tbl_barangay as b
ON h.cbrgycode=b.cbrgycode
WHERE b.cbrgyname = 'AGAO' AND m.crelationdesc !='Brgy. Captain' 
GROUP BY m.creldesc 
ORDER BY tot DESC
```

Your current query approach of `... FROM tbl_member, tbl_barangay, tbl_household LEFT JOIN tbl_religion ...` is wrong and will produce syntax error.

Comment: but how can I have that output above ?

Comment: still i cant achieve what i want to output above

Comment: The output is the same , still displays the religion which is present in tbl_member

Answer (score 0):

You can not make this:

FROM @TABLE1, @TABLE2, @TABLE3 
 LEFT JOIN @TABLE0 ON ...

You can select items only from a table at once... same for join.

```
SELECT m.creldesc as type, 
COUNT(m.creldesc) as tot, 
SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male, 
SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female 
FROM tbl_member as m

LEFT JOIN tbl_religion z ON z.creldesc = m.creldesc 
LEFT JOIN tbl_barangay h ON h.cbrgycode=b.cbrgycode

SO ON.... WITH JOINS
    GROUP BY m.creldesc
```

**UPDATE WOKING CODE:**

```
SELECT m.creldesc as type, COUNT(m.creldesc) as tot, SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female 

FROM tbl_member as m
    LEFT JOIN tbl_religion r ON r.creldesc = m.creldesc 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_barangay as b ON m.chholdnumber = b.cbrgycode 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_household as h  ON h.cbrgycode = b.cbrgycode

WHERE b.cbrgyname = 'AGAO' and m.crelationdesc !='Brgy. Captain' 
GROUP BY m.creldesc 
ORDER BY tot DESC
```

Comment: but how can I have that output above ?  im a bit confused with left join\

Comment: you make exactly the select you have above... but when you join the tables you make something like this...

SELECT m.creldesc as type, COUNT(m.creldesc) as tot, SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN m.cgender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female 
  
 FROM tbl_member as m
  LEFT JOIN tbl_religion r ON r.creldesc = m.creldesc 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_barangay as b ON m.chholdnumber = b.cbrgycode
  LEFT JOIN tbl_household as h  ON h.cbrgycode = b.cbrgycode
 
 WHERE b.cbrgyname = 'AGAO' and m.crelationdesc !='Brgy. Captain' 
 GROUP BY m.creldesc 
 ORDER BY tot DESC

Comment: I tried that but still i get the same output above still, i cannot display all remaining religions with 0 values @SanRyu

Comment: That is weard... the join is ok... I don't actually understand what you really need... what do you want for your output to have ?

Comment: the updated code still not working Ive change the LEFT JOIN tbl_household line since h.cbrgycode is not connected to b.cbrgycode there's no such cbrgycode on tbl_household. but still the same output @SanRyu

Comment: Usually ... the join aren't made on varchars, is better to do on IDs... but for that you need to restructure the tables...

Comment: So if i add another field for tbl_religion such as religion id and reference it to tbl_member, can I achieve the output above ?

Comment: something like that... you need a base table and the affiliate tables that reference to the base one !! joined on id's !